# BeautifulStoneSoup - how to unescape and add closing tags

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm editing the original post here to clarify and hopefully I have boiled it down into something more manageable.  I have a string of xml that looks something like:

```
<foo id="foo">
    <row>
        &lt;img alt="jules.png" src="http://localhost/jules.png" height="1024" width="764"&gt;
    </row>
    <row>
        &lt;img alt="hairfire.png" src="http://localhost/hairfire.png" height="225" width="225"&gt;
    </row>
</foo>
```

So, I'm doing something like:

```
xml = BeautifulStoneSoup(someXml, selfClosingTags=['img'], convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
```

The result of that is something like:

```
<foo id="foo">
    <row>
        <img alt="jules.png" src="http://localhost/jules.png" height="1024" width="764">
    </row>
    <row>
        <img alt="hairfire.png" src="http://localhost/hairfire.png" height="225" width="225">
    </row>
</foo>
```

Notice there are no closing tags on the img tags in each .  Not sure this is my issue, but possible. When I try and do:

```
images = xml.findAll('img')
```

it's is yielding an empty list.  Any ideas why BeautifulStoneSoup wouldn't find my images in this snippet of xml?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not finding the img tags is because BeautifulSoup is treating them as the text part of the "row" tag. Converting entities just changes the strings, it doesn't change the underlying structure of the document. The following isn't a great solution (it parses the document twice), but it worked when I tested it on your sample xml. The idea here is to convert the text to bad xml, then have beautiful soup clean it up again.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(BeautifulSoup(text,convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES).prettify())
print soup.findAll('img')
```